# Suppress unused variable error for destructured arrays

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I'm destructuring the result of a regex match

```
function getStuffIWant(str: string): string {
    const [
        fullMatch,   // [ts] 'fullMatch' is declared but its value is never read.
        stuffIWant,
    ] = str.match(/1(.*)2/);

    return stuffIWant;
}

getStuffIWant("abc1def2ghi");
```

As the comment points out, `fullMatch` is never used and TSC wants me to know.  **Is there any way to suppress this error without turning off unused checks across the board?**

I've also tried unpacking the array as an object:

```
const {
    1: stuffIWant, // Unexpected SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
} = str.match(/1(.*)2/);
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Found an answer almost immediately (ain't it always the way) - when destructuring arrays you can [ignore select values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values) by adding an extra comma in:

```
function getStuffIWant(str: string): string {
    const [
        , // full match
        stuffIWant,
    ] = str.match(/1(.*)2/);

    return stuffIWant;
}

getStuffIWant("abc1def2ghi");
```

No variable declared, nothing for TypeScript to get all up in arms about.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative syntax as of TypeScript 4.2:

```
function getStuffIWant(str: string): string {
  const [
      _fullMatch,
      stuffIWant,
  ] = str.match(/1(.*)2/);

  return stuffIWant;
}

getStuffIWant("abc1def2ghi");
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#destructured-variables-can-be-explicitly-marked-as-unused

**Note**: `str.match` can also return `null`, so the example in the question has an additional compilation error due to ts(2461)

Comment: This works for TS warnings, but my IDE still complains about it separately, seems like it may not be consistently applicable.